# migrating data from SQL Server 2014 downwards to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, import, export

Any direction or guidelines for migrating exporting data from SQL Server 2014 downwards importing to SQL Server 2012

Thanks

Comment: use ssis, or migration scripts or query from synonyms, There is nothing as `Downwards`, you are importing data from one server to another server. You can even create triggers with linked server connection for any new data update

Answer (score 0):

generated the create script for all objects and create it in your target server.Then use  DataX ,or Navicat to migrate data .